# What smartphone doesn't necessitate me to have any application besides basic applications (as defined)?

Tags: smartphones, mobile-phone

I use *OnePlus 6* smartphone which I bought about 18 months ago; I generally really like this smartphone and generally happy I bought it.
<sub>Putting aside the `cannot-be-deleted` and `in-my-opinion-crappy` "Zen mode" of the Oxygen (Android) OS of One Plus.</sub>

### My problem

I was always annoyed from the fact that Android always necessitated me to have some applications installed even if I didn't want them installed and only let me "disable" them, if at all to have and couldn't delete them.

This has become very annoying with new apps of Andorid 10, that I can't even disable, such as:

- **File manager**
- **Game Space**

I also always had an application which I always found redundant: "Sim toolkit".

### My question

What smartphone doesn't necessitate me to have any application besides basic applications (as defined):

- settings
- store
- calendar
- clock
- sms
- phone
- Calculator
- Camera
- Files (with an option to create a folder for images without one created for me in ways I won't necessarily like)

**?**

<sub>**Note:** I also use native Notes apps often but I wouldn't necessarily want to use one that come with such smartphone (I might want to integrate my Microsoft Windows notes with those of the smartphone so I would need another app).</sub>

Comment: I'd look through the ROMs on XDA developers and buy an appropriate used phone. You may also check out LineageOS. In general you are unlikely to find such a smartphone on the market simply because you're in a minority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest moving from an Android to a iOS (due to iOS's weird way it handles restoring from an Android backup) but if you wanted it from brand new, no contacts or pictures, iPhones are pretty reliable and don't force many apps on you. It comes installed with some useless apps for most people, but pretty much all of those can be deleted. Here are the apps on an iPhone that are forced (this is on a iPhone XR, on iOS 13.3).

- Photos
- Wallet
- Camera
- Clock
- Health
- Phone
- Messages
- Find My (Finds your iDevices and friends)
- Settings
- App Store

There are productivity apps avalible, and a file app but those are optional.